# Why doesn't getopts('absif:', \%Options) report an error when I pass an invalid option?

Tags: perl

#### file.pl

```
if (! getopts('abisf:',\%Options)){
# Display usage details
print "Usage Error invalid options \n";
exit(1);
}
```

If I run:

```
$>perl file.pl -q @argv;
```

This should print the usage error but it doesn't.

```
$>perl file.pl -a @argv;
```

This should have `$Options{a}=1` but what I see is `$Options{a}=''` i.e null.

What's going on?

Comment: Which `Getopt::*` module are you using?

Comment: This code works fine with `Getopt::Std`, although the `@argv;` command line parameter seems a little odd...

Answer (score 1):

Remember to post an [Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compiling) Example](http://sscce.org/) whenever possible; it makes it much easier for people to help you reliably.

Here's an SSCCE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;

my %Options;

if (! getopts('abisf:',\%Options)){
# Display usage details
print "Usage Error invalid options \n";
exit(1);
}

for my $opt (sort keys %Options)
{
    print "-$opt = $Options{$opt}\n";
}
for my $arg (@ARGV)
{
    print "arg = $arg\n";
}
print "OK\n";
```

When the script is called `opt.pl` and it is invoked as shown below, it seems to work correctly:

```
$ perl opt.pl
OK
$ perl opt.pl -a
-a = 1
OK
$ perl opt.pl -a x
-a = 1
arg = x
OK
$ perl opt.pl -a -f x
-a = 1
-f = x
OK
$ perl opt.pl -a -f x zzz
-a = 1
-f = x
arg = zzz
OK
$ perl opt.pl -q
Unknown option: q
Usage Error invalid options 
$
```

Do you see anything unexpected in the output?  What did you get on your system?